# How to change Login default blue admin color?

Tags: customization, login

How can I change default blue admin color for *selected* *button* or *checkmark* in Wordpress standard login page with CSS?

[image: Default blue selected button border and chekmark]

This is the default blue color I mean, used for selected button border and chekmark... I don't mean the normal button border color, but the color around it after you click on it or used for the selected checkmark...

EDIT: you can ignore customizations shown in the pic above. Standard Wordpress login is the same and uses that default blue color I'd like to change for button outline and checkmarks in the login/lost pass page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.wp-core-ui .button-primary.focus, .wp-core-ui .button-primary:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 0px #007cba !important;
}
```

or replace the color with something that goes with your background:

```
#007cba
```

Comment: Thank you! ...Ideas for the checkmark color?